# git lfs push fails with HTTP error 404

Tags: git, https, http-status-code-404, git-lfs

Im a newbie on git so be gentle please. Not sure how much more info I should give so please ask me.

We are using git v2.11.0.windows.3.
We have set up in our office a Bonobo server to use GIT.
We have enabled git lfs and I have managed to commit and push to origin all our *.png files. Three months later and I am trying to add all *.ico files but it fails to push with the following error:

> $ GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs push --all origin HEAD
>
> 17:54:35.173243 git.c:607               trace: exec: 'git-lfs' 'push' '--all' 'origin' 'HEAD'
>
> 17:54:35.173243 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git-lfs' 'push' '--all' 'origin' 'HEAD'
>
> 17:54:35.204260 trace git-lfs: run_command: 'git' version
>
> 17:54:35.285145 trace git-lfs: run_command: 'git' config -l
>
> 17:54:35.353218 trace git-lfs: tq: running as batched queue, batch size of 100
>
> 17:54:35.353218 trace git-lfs: Upload refs [HEAD] to remote origin
>
> 17:54:36.289653 trace git-lfs: run_command: git rev-list --objects --do-walk HEAD --
>
> 17:54:36.296699 trace git-lfs: run_command: git cat-file --batch
>
> 17:54:36.390751 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 100
>
> 17:54:36.390751 trace git-lfs: api: batch 100 files
>
> 17:54:36.404759 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> 17:54:36.442780 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 404
>
> 17:54:36.442780 trace git-lfs: api error: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>   Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
>
> 17:54:36.455788 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 100
>
> 17:54:36.455788 trace git-lfs: api: batch 100 files
>
> 17:54:36.456788 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> 17:54:36.466794 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 404
>
> 17:54:36.466794 trace git-lfs: api error: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
>
> 17:54:36.993166 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 95
>
> 17:54:36.993166 trace git-lfs: api: batch 95 files
>
> 17:54:36.993166 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> 17:54:37.009174 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 404
>
> 17:54:37.009174 trace git-lfs: api error: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
>
> Git LFS: (0 of 295 files) 0 B / 4.06 MB
>
> batch response: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
>   batch response: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
>   batch response: Repository or object not found: _https://blah.com/Git/Hippotizer.git/info/lfs/objects/batch/objects/batch
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it

We havent changed anything in our server so can't figure out why I was able to push 3 months ago but not now.

Answer (score 1):

Bonobo has not supported LFS yet. You could push PNG files probably because they were not tracked by LFS.

https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/342